# Vuetifyjs grid not resizing in small screens

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Am using vuetifyjs and i expect this to resize to full screen width in small screens but have a ratio of 4 and 8 in big screen but this fails resize in small screen

I have added

```
            <v-row justify="center" align="center">
                <v-col cols="12" md="3" sm="6" v-for="(item,key) in 4" :key="key">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
```

This works with md but small screen doesnt resize to 6

The small screen shows

[image]

On a big screen it displays

[image]

Why does the small screen not scale to halfway but large screen works.What am i missing out?

Answer (score 1):

`cols="12" md="3" sm="6"`

**Description**

`cols="12"` this column will shrink to 12 columns

`sm="6"` this column will shrink to 6 columns on small (600px) and greater breakpoints.

`md="3"` this column will shrink to 3 columns on medium (960px) and greater breakpoints.

**So it works correctly**

Set the raw `cols` attribute to something that you want to be shown on the "small" (smaller than 600px) screens.

I suppose the parameters `cols="6"  md="3"` will do what you want.

More about the grid: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids